# Mean function incorrect value

Tags: julia, mean

I have an 80 element array with the same entries: 176.019779658138**53**

If I use the mean function I will get the value 176.019779658138**42**

Why is that?

---

Here is a minimal working example:

```
using Statistics
arr = fill(176.01977965813853, 80)

julia> mean(arr)
176.01977965813842
```

I expected this to return `176.01977965813853`.

Comment: You don't say how you get the other value. Anyways, the results seem to agree up to floating point precision.

Comment: I think the question means that it contains a single identical value 80 times. But yes, correct to numerical precision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem as I understand it can be reproduced as follows:

```
using Statistics
arr = fill(176.01977965813853, 80)

julia> mean(arr)
176.01977965813842
```

The reason for this is that julia does all floating point arithmetic with 64 bits of precision by default (i.e. the `Float64` type). `Float64`s *cannot* represent any real number. There is a finite step between each floating point number and rounding errors are incurred when you do arithmetic on them. These rounding errors are usually fine, but if you're not careful, they can be catastrophic. For instance:

```
julia> 1e100 + 1.0 - 1e100
0.0
```

That says that if I do `10^100 + 1 - 10^100` I get zero! If you want to get an upper bound on the errors caused by floating point arithmetic, we can use IntervalArithmetic.jl:

```
using IntervalArithmetic

julia> 1e100 + interval(1.0) - 1e100
[0, 1.94267e+84]
```

That says that the operation `1e100 + 1.0 - 1e100` is at least equal to `0.0` and at most `1.94*10^84`, so the error bounds are huge!

We can do the same for the operation you were interested in,

```
arr = fill(interval(176.01977965813853), 80);

julia> mean(arr)
[176.019, 176.02]

julia> mean(arr).lo
176.019779658138

julia> mean(arr).hi
176.0197796581391
```

which says that the *actual* mean could be at least `176.019779658138` or at most `176.0197796581391`, but one can't be any more certain due to floating point error! So here, `Float64` gave the answer with at most `10^-13` *percent* error, which is actually quite small.

What if those are unacceptable error bounds? Use more precision! You can use the `big` string macro to get arbitrary precision number literals:

```
arr = fill(interval(big"176.01977965813853"), 80);

julia> mean(arr).lo
176.0197796581385299999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999546

julia> mean(arr).hi
176.019779658138530000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000043
```

That calculation was done using 256 bits of precision, but you can get even more precision using the `setprecision` function:

```
setprecision(1000)
arr = fill(interval(big"176.01977965813853"), 80);

julia> mean(arr).lo
176.019779658138529999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999599

julia> mean(arr).hi
176.019779658138530000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000579
```

Note that arbitrary precision arithmetic is *sloooow* compared to `Float64`s, so it's usually best to just use arbitrary precision arithmetic to validate your results to make sure you're converging to a good result within your desired accuracy.

Answer (score 4):

These are just expected floating point errors. But if you need very precise summations, you can use a a bit more elaborate (and costly) summation scheme:

```
julia> using KahanSummation
[ Info: Precompiling KahanSummation [8e2b3108-d4c1-50be-a7a2-16352aec75c3]

julia> sum_kbn(fill(176.01977965813853, 80))/80
176.01977965813853
```

Ref: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm)